# How to use stat command inside awk

Tags: bash, awk, system-calls, stat

I would like to use the stat command inside awk to achieve a modification time in seconds of listed files. I  want to keep the output information from stat in a variable and further process inside awk. How to format the command to achieve this objective?

```
ls -la | awk '{ system("a=$(stat -c %Y $9)");    (further operation on a...)  }'
```

Thanks in advance

Dominik

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`bash` has no `stat` command. `bash` is a shell, an application whose primary goal is to run other commands and make them interact together.

`stat` is the name of a few different applications, with different syntax whose primary goal is to be an interface to the `stat(2)` system call, that is to get and output metadata information about a file.

The one you seem to be referring to seems to be GNU `stat`. `zsh` is the only shell to my knowledge that has a *builtin* stat command (with different syntax).

`awk` is yet another application, an interpreter for the `awk` language, whose primary goal is to do text processing. The `awk` language has a system() function that's used to run a shell (`sh`, not `bash`) command line.

With:

```
awk '{system("a=$(stat -c %Y $9)")}'
```

`awk` starts a new process that executes a `sh` interpreter. That shell sets its *own* a variable to the output of `stat` and then exits. So, that's not useful. What you want is set an `awk` variable.

You'll do that with `awk`'s equivalent of the shell's command subtitution (`$(...)`):

```
awk '{"stat -c %Y " $9  | getline a; ...}'
```

However, there, `awk`'s 9th field ends up being expanded and included in the code passed to the shell that interprets that `stat...` command line, so it becomes a code injection vulnerability. For instance if `$9` is `x;reboot` (a perfectly valid file name), the command line becomes `stat -c %Y x;reboot` and that will run the `reboot` command.

Now, note that GNU `ls` can output the unix time by itself.

```
ls -l --time-style=+%s
```

Or you could also use `GNU` `find` to get something that is reliably parseable:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -printf '%Ts/%s/%p\0' |
  while IFS=/ read -d '' -r mtime size name; do
    something with "$mtime" "$size" "$name"
  done
```

(here using `/` as the delimiter as it's the only character guaranteed not to be found at the end of the paths as output by `find`)

`find` will also get you sub-second granularity where available with `%T@` instead of `%Ts`.

Comment: In my opinion you deserve to be the person that have answered for my question in the way that I have expected. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '{ "stat -c %Y " $9 | getline a; stuff_with_a; }'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need awk, you could always use

```
find $(pwd) -exec stat \{} --printf="%y\n" \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Small addition to what was said.
When having a large number of files:

```
awk '{ fh="stat -c %Y " $9; fh | getline a; close(fh); stuff_with_a; }'
```

Otherwise you hit "too many files open".